# Programs disconnecting my Ethernet cable connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet, steam

Certain programs disconnects my ethernet cable connection.

I'm gaming on a desktop, connected to the internet using ethernet cable.
My problem with Dota 2 or CS:GO or any Steam games for that matter is they would disconnect my ethernet cable connection to my modem. It's like it highjacked my device and it happens randomly.

Literally, the LAN ports lights would go off, **replugging** the cable doesn't work. Going to the settings to switch OFF/ON **WIRED** is impossible as the option for the WIRED>>ON is grayed out(similar to if you don't have an ethernet cable plugged in)
Restarting the modem doesn't work, the LAN lights are still off. It's basically the device's problem now.

I know a particular option in Windows 10 where it would not allow programs to take control of the Ethernet Network Device(this doesn't solve the problem though as in Win10, the device would freeze when Steam wants to disconnect but I'd still like to try) but I couldn't find something similar in Ubuntu settings.

I know this is Steam's fault as this problem only started in 2018 but what do they care for the minority.

Comment: How did you determine this a software issue ? My first thought would be to try another cable, as this may be a poor contact. Ethernet cables are fragile.

Comment: I have no spare cable to test this but this only happens when I am playing Dota 2 or CS:GO.
I never seen my Ubuntu's(since 2019) network icon totally disappear in the toolbar unless I manually turn it off. 

When internet goes out I just notice a question mark  on the network icon and modem's internet light go out too but when this bug happens, it totally takes out the network icon along with the LAN light on the modem.

It's also a known issue in the Dota 2 forums but no solution was provided since 2018.

Comment: Also, if it's just the physical connection, reconnecting the cable should restore the internet like if you would deliberately disconnect and reconnect it but it doesn't. 

Back when I was using Win10, same thing also happens, restarting the device is the only solution but by the time you get back into the game, you're already penalized as a quiter.

Comment: Do you have a link outlining that known issue ? Maybe then we can think of a possible workaround.

Comment: Yes. experiences may vary, back when I was in windows 10, this would happen after 20-25 seconds after the game starts.

This one is for Windows 10 - https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/5i339k/dota_2_disconnecting_windows_10_internet/

Luckily, In ubuntu, it's random, but in the past 2 days it happens on the loading screen before the game starts OR at the end of the game after a winner is determined. 

Dota 2 disconnects my whole internet - https://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=281382
https://steamcommunity.com/app/570/discussions/0/1291817837628891320/

Comment: This happened to me before I got this present problem which is a lighter version. Browsers are works but Steam itself is not connected to the internet. Restarting the steam solves this though. Looks like this problem is progressive -https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/2tdz2e/network_problem_autodisconnect_in_25_seconds/

Exact same problem - https://www.dotabuff.com/topics/2017-12-13-dota-killing-internet

I've already tried running dota alone, even closing the windows of steam so ONLY Dota 2 runs and steam on the background.

Before this, I could still restart my network but now, no

Comment: Update:

Someone suggested to change DNS so I followed the instruction in `https://datawookie.netlify.app/blog/2018/10/dns-on-ubuntu-18.04/`, this time my PC would crash(not restart) completely.

In CS:GO, it would only happen on the any first round so I can't finishing a single round at all.